# Block statements in if-else

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Hive supports conditional statements - https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions

However, I wish to use a **block** conditional statements. For example, I have two tables A and B that have similar columns (although column names aren't identical). I wish to create a new table from A and B such that B has higher priority. So, if a row is present in B, I wish to select it from B, else select the row from A.
i.e.

```
SELECT 
IF (B.id<>NULL,
      (B.id as id,
       B.value1 as value),
      (A.id as id,
       a.value2 as value))
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON (A.id = B.id)
```

The above query doesn't work. Is it because Hive doesn't support block conditional statements? How can I implement the above functionality?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't know about block conditional statements, but wouldn't this achieve the same thing:

```
select case when b.id is null then a.id else b.id end as id,
       case when b.id is null then a.value else b.value end as value
from a
full outer join b on ( a.id = b.id )
```

Comment: Yes, this is right. I too came up with this. The problem is there are around 10 columns. I was wondering if there was an elegant way of writing this instead of using 10 case statements. Thanks!

Comment: You might also look at Hive's struct() type so you could just use a single case statement: select case when b.id is null then struct(a.id, a.value) else struct(b.id, b.value) end as id_val ... though then you'll also want an answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737914/is-there-a-tidier-syntax-for-convert-a-hive-struct-back-to-regular-columns